# Getting error while executing AsyncTask in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am Getting an error  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()  while executing

here is my doInBackground() method

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


            AlertDialog.Builder rewardedAdvert = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlayGame.this);
            View rView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rewardedads, null);
            homeButton = (Button) rView.findViewById(R.id.homebutton);


            homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    gameOver();
                }
            });
            rewardedAdvert.setView(rView);

            AlertDialog dialog = rewardedAdvert.create();
          dialog.getWindow().setLayout(700, 700);


        return null;
    }
```

here is the method where i am calling AsyncTask

```
  private void wrongAnswer() {
    correctImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    wrongImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((LightQuiz) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.playWrongSound();
    lives--;
    if (lives == 0) {

       new GameOverRewardedAds().execute();

      //  gameOver();




    }
```

here is the logcat:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                            at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:119)
                                                                            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:200)
                                                                            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:1086)
                                                                            at com.awwalsoft.javaplay.PlayGame$GameOverRewardedAds.doInBackground(PlayGame.java:429)
                                                                            at com.awwalsoft.javaplay.PlayGame$GameOverRewardedAds.doInBackground(PlayGame.java:387)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: can you post the entire logcat

Comment: You aren't doing any task rather than UI stuff in your `doInBackground` method. You can move all the code to the `onPostExecute` or completely remove the `AyncTask` and move the `doInBackground` code to your `wrongAnswer` method

Comment: please check the logcat in below section  @DroiDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **doInBackground** is not executing on the UI thread but on the different thread and you can't touch views created on UI thread  from background thread. Also, in your **AsyncTask** you are not doing anything that needs to be done in the background, so you can move all the stuff to your activity which runs on the UI thread.

Main reason for using AsyncTask is some lengthy job that would freeze your UI if it's done on the main thread. If you are just dealing with your views and performing short tasks then leave it on the main thread.

Comment: actually it's taking so long time to load the AlertDialog and after the AlertDialog is loading when i clicked a button available on AlertDialog is also taking long time to execute

Comment: well, just as I wrote, UI operations belong to the UI thread, please try to move your code to your activity